# Tracking views in an entries loop with more than one result

Tags: entries, tracking

I’m trying to use the ‘track_views’ parameter to record impressions of banners which are being served on a website. Am I correct in thinking that track_views is *only* supported on single entry pages, i.e. if I have a channel:entries loop that outputs more than 1 entry it will not track views?

Comment: I think that is correct - someone chime in if that's wrong.

Comment: Benek is correct. Tracking views does as its title suggests and doesnt track the origin of the viewing. You could setup a template and redirect to that template & track views to it. The template could then redirect to actual template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. :) Your inkling is correct in that `track_views` is only supported on single entry pages specified by title or ID. Multiple entries can be output with the {view_count} displayed but views will not be incremented. I'd love to expand a little but I can't really think of a good way around this as the [entry tracking](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_tracking.html) is pretty rigid.

For banner/advertising impressions however it would probably be better to go with a more versatile option such as Google Analytics.

Comment: Or, use google DFP to serve the ads and then all the tracking is built in.

Comment: Thanks @BenekLisefski - I suspected that this might be the case. This is a fairly simple site and advert display is tied to EE categories so I will probably stick with a native EE solution for now and hack together a plug-in to increment views inside an entries loop. :)